# Cannot connect to localstack docker endpoint?

Tags: docker, macos, terminal, localstack

I have successfully installed `localstack` via `python3 -m pip install localstack`. I can verify it is installed as `localstack --version` yields 3.1.0.

I then ran localstack via `localstack start -d` and can verify that it is running within Docker desktop. (See both the screenshot, and the pasted logs below): [image]

`22024-01-30 22:25:58`
`2024-01-30 22:25:58 LocalStack version: 3.1.1.dev`
`2024-01-30 22:25:58 LocalStack Docker container id: 57a336aa2797`
`2024-01-30 22:25:58 LocalStack build date: 2024-01-31`
`2024-01-30 22:25:58 LocalStack build git hash: 4a5f76e9`
`2024-01-30 22:25:58` 
`2024-01-30 22:25:59 2024-01-31T03:25:59.436  INFO --- [-functhread4] hypercorn.error            : Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)`
`2024-01-30 22:25:59 2024-01-31T03:25:59.436  INFO --- [-functhread4] hypercorn.error            : Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)`
`2024-01-30 22:25:59 Ready.`

All of this suggests to me that localstack is running correctly within this docker container (though I am a bit confused why Port(s) lists `4510:4510` and the log says its at `https://0.0.0.0:4566`).

In any case, I wanted to test that it works, so I ran the following in the terminal:

```
aws --endpoint-url=https://0.0.0.0:4566 s3api create-bucket --bucket my-bucket --region us-east-1
```

This yields an error of `zsh: command not found: aws`. Further, clicking on the 4510:4510 link in "Port(s)" sends me to a URL where "Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection".

I have tried replacing `https://0.0.0.0:4566` with `http://localhost:4566`, `http://localhost:4510` and `https://0.0.0.0:4510`. All yield same error.

I do not have the AWS CLI installed on my computer, but I am curious why this matters if I am pointing the command at the localstack docker URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 4510 is an external service port. To give you some context, LocalStack in its early days used to spin up various local AWS services on varying ports (S3 on 4572, Kinesis on 4568, etc.). This was replaced by a single edge port 4566 which acts as the main entry point for all API invocations.

When you spin up LocalStack, it will open various ports (starting from 4510 to 4560. When a LocalStack service starts an external service, it automatically selects an available port from within the specified range.
The primary advantage of this approach is that these ports are accessible from outside the Docker container, allowing direct access to the external service without the need for LocalStack to act as a proxy.

Coming onto the second part of the question — It appears that you are missing AWS CLI on your host machine. LocalStack allows you to create local AWS resources through various integrations, such as AWS CLI, Terraform, CDK, etc. These integrations work by pointing an internal AWS endpoint URL parameter to the LocalStack edge port. If you're interested, you can read the [open-source code for `awslocal` to see how this is made possible](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local/blob/master/bin/awslocal).

**TL;DR** — Install AWS CLI, create a [LocalStack profile](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/aws-cli/#configuring-a-custom-profile) or [install `awslocal`](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/aws-cli/#localstack-aws-cli-awslocal), and get started with your LocalStack operations.

Comment: Your TLDR includes this but not the body... having the AWS CLI installed on my local machine is necessary for the awslocal wrapper to work? Just the latter isn't sufficient?

Comment: awslocal is a wrapper around AWS CLI. Its absolutely necessary to have AWS CLI installed to make it work. If you don't have AWS CLI installed, awslocal will install the AWS CLI v1 on your machine: https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local/blob/5b38bc5f3e954298c27a1895578390398f968814/setup.py#L32